# service broker queue index growing beyond control

Tags: sql-server-2016, clustered-index, service-broker

We have a queue that was set up about ten years ago in 2008. We have been running it on an Azure VM Standard edition sql 2016 for about 3 years no with no problems.

In the last 3 months, with no changes to the code or platform, we are seeing MASSIVE issues. The service broker index has become massive. There are about 100 million pages and counting, even though there are only 400 rows of data. As a result the database has ballooned out from 50GB to about 400gb, which is causing massive issues downstream.

I am convinced we are not tidying up messages or there are poisoned messages in the queue somewhere, but nothing i have found online seems to help me figure out were to look first.

We have been through the code and recommendations and everything seems to be in order.

the query used to find out the number of pages and rows.

```
SELECT TOP 5
    SCHEMA_NAME(itab.schema_id) AS 'schema_name',
    itab.name AS 'internal_table_name',
    idx.name AS 'heap_or_index_name',
    p.*,
    au.*
FROM
    sys.internal_tables AS itab
JOIN sys.indexes AS idx
    --     JOIN to the heap or the clustered index  
        ON itab.object_id = idx.object_id
           AND idx.index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
JOIN sys.partitions AS p
    ON p.object_id = idx.object_id
       AND p.index_id = idx.index_id
JOIN sys.allocation_units AS au
    --     IN_ROW_DATA (type 1) and ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA (type 3) => JOIN to partition's Hobt  
--     else LOB_DATA (type 2) => JOIN to the partition ID itself.  
        ON au.container_id = CASE au.type
                               WHEN 2 THEN p.partition_id
                               ELSE p.hobt_id
                             END
ORDER BY
    au.total_pages DESC
```

This is what we are seeing, no rows, massive number of pages.
[image]
It feels like its no longer removing pages, or there are a large number of messages in the table that dont show up anywhere. being able to see what is in the table when it claims to be empty would be useful.

This time 6 months ago when the rows were low, so were the pages used and total pages. In fact its clean everywhere but production.

UPDATE:
5 days after reducing traffic to it and a random reboot on a firewall server
[image]

without doing any changes its back to normal. last night 14 million pages, this morning 132. What is going on?

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by "the service broker index has become massive". It may help if you include the query you ran to identify the space usage to your question.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Edited